# IDataErrorInfo in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, idataerrorinfo

Can IDataError info be used properly in a winforms application? In the past I was doing my binding the usual way(1) and did the validation in the OnValidating event of the particular control. I would like to move the data validation to the domain model so that I can easily swap out user interfaces and so that all of the logic is in one place.

I was looking into IDataErrorInfo but everything I find deals with WPF and the app in development is strictly a winforms app.

I also noticed that the binding that gets used in WPF is in System.Windows.Data and the binding that I've always been using is in System.Windows.Forms (which I don't appear to have when I try to add it as a resource - I'm using 3.5).Aside from the property "ValidatesOnDataErrors" is there a difference between the two?

(1) the usual way being:

```
myControl.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.domainModel, "Property"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works with the [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) component in Windows Forms.

For a complete, but very simple and short tutorial, see [this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20070423051752/http://codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/objectdatasource-and-idataerrorinfo-with-winforms-AID427.aspx).

Comment: +1 Fantastic blog post. Cured all of my current woes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like the link to the *fantastic blog post* is broken: making this link only answer obsolete.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå It's actually not a link-only answer.  The suggestion about `ErrorProvider` makes this an answer without the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `IDataErrorInfo` works in winforms. For example, `DataGridView` will use this automatically both per-row and per-cell. But it is implementation-specific, and isn't *automatically* applied to other bindings. I did once write some code to associate it to an error-provider and do the work via change events, but I don't have it to hand unfortunately. But I seem to recall it wasn't huge.